# calling function within class structure producing bound method error

Tags: python, function, class, structure

I'm trying to use this class to streamline EDA:

```
class EDA:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        
    def initial_eda_checks(df):
        if df.isnull().sum().sum() > 0:
            mask_total = df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False) 
            total = mask_total[mask_total > 0]

            mask_percent = df.isnull().mean().sort_values(ascending=False) 
            percent = mask_percent[mask_percent > 0] 

            missing_data = pd.concat([total, percent], axis=1, keys=['Total', 'Percent'])
    
            print(f'Total and Percentage of NaN:\n {missing_data}')
        else: 
            print('No NaN found.')
```

but running into bound method error when trying to run the code

```
eda = EDA(acc_df)
eda.initial_eda_checks

<bound method EDA.initial_eda_checks of <EDA_Class.EDA object at 0x0000027CFDEE1340>
```

A bit new to using classes and functions so forgive me, but I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `def initial_eda_checks(self):` and then replace all `df` with `self.df` within the method. You also need to call the method: `eda.initial_eda_checks()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I'll give it a try